# How to make an array list to loop it self, while being in a loop?

Tags: java, sql, loops, arraylist

Right I've got 3 model classes and 3 of those get data from the database (different tables) via SQL and save data into arraylists. 
Now I'm trying to input three array lists data into the table. 
The problem is that 2 array lists (closing and closing2) have got same amount of data and 1 array list has got only 4 values. What I want is that it would output in table as a 0 if the date from arraylist does not match date in other arraylists.

It is done by an IF statement that checks if dates are equal.

The problem is that arraylist closing1 has only got 4 values and it will not let to loop through all other arraylists more than 4 times.

The question is, how can I still keep looping through arraylists closing and closing 2 and start looping through arraylist closing1 from beginning?

```
try{

       Model_Closing[] closing = Model_Closing.QueryWhere();
       Model_Closing_DIV[] closing1 = Model_Closing_DIV.QueryWhere();
       //Model_Closing_VisUnit[] closing2 = Model_Closing_VisUnit.QueryWhere();

       model.setRowCount(0);
       for(int i=0; i < closing.length; i++)
          if (closing1[i].GetDate().equals(closing[i].GetDate())){                                
        model.insertRow(i,new Object[]{date=closing[i].GetDate(),openingDollarBalance = closingDollarBalance,"NA",fundValue,dollarTransactionAmount,closing[i].GetNAV() * dollarTransactionAmount,visibleUnits,closingDollarBalance,closing[i].GetNAV(),dailyDivRate=closing1[i].GetDiv(),dailyDivDollars = dailyDivRate * accruedUnits,dailyDivRate / closing[i].GetNAV(), accruedDivDollars = accruedUnits * dailyDivRate,accruedUnits = visibleUnits + dailyDivUnits, });
        }
          else {
       dailyDivRate = 0.0;  
       model.insertRow(i,new Object[]{date=closing[i].GetDate(),openingDollarBalance = closingDollarBalance,"NA",fundValue,dollarTransactionAmount,closing[i].GetNAV() * dollarTransactionAmount,visibleUnits,closingDollarBalance,closing[i].GetNAV(),dailyDivRate,dailyDivDollars = dailyDivRate * accruedUnits,dailyDivRate / closing[i].GetNAV(), accruedDivDollars = accruedUnits * dailyDivRate,accruedUnits = visibleUnits + dailyDivUnits, });      
          }


        if (closingTable == null) {
            closingTable = new JTable(model);
           add(new JScrollPane(closingTable));
        }
       else{
            closingTable.setModel(model);
        }


    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: As it looks like you cannot give a good explanation, why not giving a good sample of the input data and the expected result?

Comment: If you recognize yourself that the question is not clear, work to clarify it. I'll try to decipher it and give you an answer, but I'm willing to bet you'll get there yourself if you succeed at making the question clear.

Comment: Are you wanting an inner loop a loop inside a loop?

Comment: Format your code too.

Comment: In your inner loop you are incrementing i and doing < i instead of b?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how can i still keep looping through arraylists
>   closing and closing 2 and start looping through arraylist closing1
>   from begining?

I guess what you need is:

```
closing1[i%closing1.length].GetDate()== closing[i].GetDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Under another understanding of the question,

```
Date date1 = (i < closing1.size()) ? closing1[i].GetDate() : zero;
date1 == closing[i].getDate();
```

where `zero` is whatever date that will "output in table as a 0"

Comment: I think what I need is a nested loop? which will check the condition if closing1.GetDate == to closing.GetDate... if it is output the value into the table if not put 0. As there are only 4 values in closing1 it has to loop over again comparing the dates to closing again